# Call Bluemix service from outside app

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, ibm-watson

I've built a simple `translate service` with `Node-Red` and `Watson`. The service is ok when called directly from the browser but I have an error ( `CORS` ) when call the service via `http` from my `Angular app`.

Does `Bluemix` allow `CORS` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these code lines in your ***bluemix-settings.js*** and repush your app

```
// The following property can be used to configure cross-origin resource sharing
    // in the HTTP nodes.
    // See https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors#configuration-options for
    // details on its contents. The following is a basic permissive set of options:
   httpNodeCors: {
      origin: "*",
     methods: "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
    },
```

Add this code after "  *functionGlobalContext: { },* "

Comment: Thank you very much Crescenzo. That's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking Bluemix supports applications that are composed of many independent services deployed to different hostnames. For each application (which can be a service API) that you push to Bluemix, the name you provide will be prepended to *.mybluemix.net.* If your application follows the best practices of a microservices architecture you will probably have two or more subcomponents that live on different hostnames. Now if you have a front-end that needs to aggregate information from these other Bluemix apps (your AngularJS app) by default the access to other subdomains will be forbidden.

The solution is to take advantage of the standard HTTP headers that are available to control cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) on the Bluemix services that you wish to provide to JavaScript clients:

- *Access-Control-Allow-Origin*
- *Access-Control-Allow-Methods*
- *Access-Control-Allow-Headers*

Take a look at the following blog post: [Cross-origin resource sharing for Bluemix APIs](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/07/17/cross-origin-resource-sharing-bluemix-apis/).